# Set buttons at the rightmost part of the page

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this is such a simple question but I'm really having a hard time when it comes to CSS and stuff like that.

So my question is how to put these two buttons at the rightmost part. Just that.

Here is my code:

```
echo "<div class='container table-responsive'>
                    <table style='width:100;'>
                            <tr>
                                <td align='right'>
                                    <h5>".$filename2."</h5>
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#$id'>
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span> View 
                                    </button>

                                    <div id='$id' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
                                        <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>

                                            <div class='modal-content'>
                                                <div class='modal-header'>
                                                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                                                    <h4 class='modal-title'>$filename2</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class='modal-body' style='overflow-y: auto;word-wrap:break-word;'>".file_get_contents($filename).
                                                "</div>
                                                <div class='modal-footer'>
                                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <a href='$filename' download class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>
                                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></span> Save
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>";
```

Here is an image of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuCng.jpg

Comment: add `float: right` to them?

Comment: Give the table width 100% rather than 100

Comment: @JeroenBellemans float:right does not change anything

Comment: @John THANK YOU! float:right works now!

Comment: for proper table you can check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can add this property:

```
float:right;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Create a new class for those buttons and add the following css property to it:

```
float: right;
```

Check the below links to find out more on this `float` property:

[Check this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_float&preval=right) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

**Option 2:** You include the following property inside your `button` tag:

```
style="float: right;"
```

Answer (score 0):

in your second td that contain buttons , use a class maybe `right-aligned`

and then use css

```
.right-aligned{
float:right;
}
```

in your second line use pixel or %(percentage) like

```
<table style='width:100%;'>
```

moreover set widths for both td as per your need,

```
<td style='width:30%;'> for first td

<td style='width:70%;'> for second td
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use these properties :

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Place buttons in the opposite order and add float:right to both buttons